# SlickGrid: How to loop through each row and set color based on the condition?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm beginner to SlickGrid. I would like to know on how to loop through each row in a grid and set row back-color based on the condition (for ex: if Age between 20 - 40, the row will have blue color, otherwise, it will have red color).

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're using `Slick.Data.DataView`, you can modify the [`getItemMetadata` method](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) to dynamically add classes to the containing row element. I am going to write this as if your `Slick.Data.DataView` instance is called `dataView`, here you go:

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = metadata(dataView.getItemMetadata);

function metadata(old_metadata_provider) {
  return function(row) {
    var item = this.getItem(row);
    var ret  = (old_metadata_provider(row) || {});

    if (item) {
      ret.cssClasses = (ret.cssClasses || '');
      if (item.age >= 20 && item.age <= 40) {
        ret.cssClasses += ' blue';
      } else {
        ret.cssClasses += ' red';
      }
    }

    return ret;
  }
}
```

This will add a class of `'blue'` or `'red'` to the row's element.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to add a class to a specific cell in the row instead of the whole row? Thanks!

Comment: Is this iterating the rows ? I do not see that in the code ..

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a formatter so your column definition would look something like this

```
{id: "delete", name: "Del", field: "del", formatter: Slick.Formatters.Delete, width: 15},
```

Add your formatters to slickgrid like this

```
(function ($) {
// register namespace
$.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
        "Formatters": {                
            "Delete": DeleteLink
        }
    }
});


function DeleteLink(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    //Logic to present whatever you want based on the cell data
    return "<a href=\"javascript:removeId('contact', '" + dataContext.folderId + "', '" + dataContext.id + "')\"><img width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\" src=\"/images/delete.png\"/></a>";
}

})(jQuery);
```